# when hover the background and/or border must expand a little on right and left

Tags: html, css

I made a page, but I want to make when you hover the div with the specific movie, to appear a backgorund with border I think like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4C1A.png - you can see on the left is when you hover the movie and on right is when is not hovering

Bassically I did something pretty simillar but i don't know why on the side (right/left) the border/background is not extended). I've tried to put something like this: with border-right/left 10px but nothing is happening

```
.item:hover {
    background-color: var(--box-bg);
    border: solid var(--box-bg);
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-right: 10px;
    border-left: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}
```

Here is my code

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@200;300;400;600;700;900&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Signika:wght@300&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap);

:root {
    --main-color: #4D6275;
    --second-color: #3F5060;

    --body-bg: #2E3841;
    --box-bg: #272F37;

    --text-color: #D5D5D5;
    --grey-color: #B2B2B2;
    --simple-color: #C3C3C3;

    --content-height: 92px;
    --space-top: 30px;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--body-bg);
    color: var(--text-color);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    top: 0;
}

.main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--body-bg);
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: var(--text-color);
    height: var(--content-height);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3B4651;
}

.nav-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 170px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-menu li ~ li {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.nav-menu li a {
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.nav-menu li a:hover {
    color: var(--grey-color);
}

.nav-menu li a i {
    padding-left: 3.5px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.nav-options {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 0 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-search {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.nav-account {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.box-account {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.box-account-name {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 2.5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*
.box-account-name i {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
*/

.nav-account-avatar-display {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3.5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.nav-account a {
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.box-account:hover {
    background-color: #3F5160;
    transform: translateY(-10%);
}

.nav-search {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.nav-search a {
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.main-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 110px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--box-bg);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.sidebar-logo {
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar-item {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar-item-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.sidebar-item i {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.sidebar-item:hover {
    background-color: #313A44;
}

.sidebar-logo:hover {
    background-color: var(--box-bg);
}

.sidebar-item a {
    color: var(--grey-color)
}

.sidebar-logo img {
    width: 50px;
}

.content-wrapper {
    margin-top: 110px;
    margin-left: 170px;
}

.header-menu {
    display: flex;
    /*align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*justify-content: left;*/
    font-size: 18px;
}

.header-item ~ .header-item {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

li.active {
    border-bottom: 2.5px solid #E3AA1E;
}

li.active a {
    color: #E2E2E2;
}

.header-item a {
    color: #9f9f9f;
}

.content-wrapper li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.list-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    width: 18%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.item:hover {
    background-color: var(--box-bg);
    border: solid var(--box-bg);
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-right: 10px;
    border-left: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.item a {
    color: unset;
}

.item img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
}

.movie-name {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 85%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.movie-time {
    margin-top: 3px;
    color: #9F9F9F;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.movie-description {
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    html {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .msg-login {
        width: 800px;
    }

    .main-login {
        width: 400px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    html {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .msg-login {
        width: 400px;
    }

    .main-login {
        width: 250px;
    }

    .box_input_auth {
        width: 150px;
    }

    .login_btn, .register_btn {
        width: 200px;
    }

    .option_help {
        margin-left: 50px;
        display: flex;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    html {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .info-login-msg {
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    
    .msg-login {
        width: 250px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?">
        
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <!-- Ionicons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css?">
        
        <!-- Load sweetalert2 -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
        
        <!-- Google Font -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
        
        

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main-nav">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Prime <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Movies <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Series <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav-options">
                <li class="nav-search">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-account">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="box-account">
                            <div class="box-account-name">
                                <span class="name-account-nav">myAccName</span>
                                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/02/3e/eb/023eebc4bcee84dda420da10d3fe1c91.jpg" class="nav-account-avatar-display">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                <li class="sidebar-logo">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="{{ asset('assets/img/amazon-logo.png') }}">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="above-text-icon"><i class="fa fa-television"></i></div>
                        <span class="sidebar-item-title">Explore</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="above-text-icon"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></div>
                        <span class="sidebar-item-title">Watchlist</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="above-text-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></div>
                        <span class="sidebar-item-title">Favorites</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="above-text-icon"><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-right"></i></div>
                        <span class="sidebar-item-title">Continue</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="above-text-icon"><i class="fa fa-history"></i></div>
                        <span class="sidebar-item-title">History</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="above-text-icon"><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i></div>
                        <span class="sidebar-item-title">Help</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-header">
            <ul class="header-menu">
                <li class="header-item"><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
                <li class="header-item active"><a href="#">New Releases</a></li>
                <li class="header-item"><a href="#">Recently Added</a></li>
                <li class="header-item"><a href="#">Recommanded</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="list-menu">
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://static.cinemagia.ro/img/db/movie/57/79/55/captain-america-the-winter-soldier-640466l.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">Captain America: The First Avanger</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">2 hr, 5 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2020<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp7248999.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">Batman</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">1 hr, 43 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2021<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fb/ff/84/fbff84ea4b51cf1524c2a95fdac2183e.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">The Flash</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">2 hr, 53 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2017<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODdkNGU0YmEtMzBkYy00ZjQzLTliMDAtMTRkMWZjMGZkMDhkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTEzNTMwNTk@._V1_.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">Arrow</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">1 hr, 59 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2019<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNGVjNWI4ZGUtNzE0MS00YTJmLWE0ZDctN2ZiYTk2YmI3NTYyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTkxNjUyNQ@@._V1_.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">Joker</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">2 hr, 48 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2021<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i0.wp.com/www.eastmojo.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Radhe-Salman-Khan-Disha-Patani-Randeep-Hooda-1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">Radhe</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">1 hr, 43 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2016<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src=https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYWQyZGQwMzktMjFhYS00MmZmLWI3ZDEtNzg3MzRmM2ZjMDc1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODY5NzkyMjA@._V1_.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">Scooby-Doo: The Sowrd and The Scoob</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">1 hr, 25 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2019<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZWRhMzdhMzEtZTViNy00YWYyLTgxZmUtMTMwMWM0NTEyMjk3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTIzOTk5ODM@._V1_.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">X-MEN: Wolverine</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">2 hr, 46 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2020<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://static.cinemagia.ro/img/db/movie/24/45/469/boss-level-566441l.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">Boss Level: Capcana timpului</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">1 hr, 45 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2015<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9c/01/5a/9c015ae8003bca7c85620cdfdbc44f99.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">White House Down</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">1 hr, 55 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2021<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTY1ODY2MTgwM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTY3Nzc3NzE@._V1_.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">London Has Fallen</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">1 hr, 43 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2021<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://flxt.tmsimg.com/assets/p9568543_p_v10_aw.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">Olympus Has Fallen</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">1 hr, 43 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2018<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZmYzMzU4NjctNDI0Mi00MGExLWI3ZDQtYzQzYThmYzc2ZmNjXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTEyMjM2NDc2._V1_UY1200_CR90,0,630,1200_AL_.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">Godzilla vs Kong</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">1 hr, 43 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2021<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZDFiZTE4NWEtMGNkNC00YjhlLTk0YjMtNDA3NWRhMjc3MTM2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyOTA5NzQ0MDQ@._V1_.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">The Ice Road</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">1 hr, 42 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2021<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNGNiNWQ5M2MtNGI0OC00MDA2LWI5NzEtMmZiYjVjMDEyOWYzXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMjM4NTM5NDY@._V1_.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-name">The Shape Of Water</div>
                    <div class="movie-time">1 hr, 43 min</div>
                    <div class="movie-description">2021<br>Action, Justice, Hero</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to me it doesnt seem that the border is expending. To me it looks like css-grid cards that change background color on hover and add a box-shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After figuring out your css--

1. You should put item width auto rather than 18%.
2. Give a different color to your border rather than same to background for a clear understanding(Optional).

**Replace your CSS with the code below**

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@200;300;400;600;700;900&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Signika:wght@300&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap);

:root {
    --main-color: #4D6275;
    --second-color: #3F5060;

    --body-bg: #2E3841;
    --box-bg: #272F37;

    --text-color: #D5D5D5;
    --grey-color: #B2B2B2;
    --simple-color: #C3C3C3;

    --content-height: 92px;
    --space-top: 30px;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--body-bg);
    color: var(--text-color);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    top: 0;
}

.main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--body-bg);
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: var(--text-color);
    height: var(--content-height);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3B4651;
}

.nav-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 170px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-menu li ~ li {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.nav-menu li a {
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.nav-menu li a:hover {
    color: var(--grey-color);
}

.nav-menu li a i {
    padding-left: 3.5px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.nav-options {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 0 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-search {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.nav-account {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.box-account {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.box-account-name {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 2.5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*
.box-account-name i {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
*/

.nav-account-avatar-display {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3.5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.nav-account a {
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.box-account:hover {
    background-color: #3F5160;
    transform: translateY(-10%);
}

.nav-search {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.nav-search a {
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.main-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 110px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--box-bg);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.sidebar-logo {
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar-item {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar-item-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.sidebar-item i {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.sidebar-item:hover {
    background-color: #313A44;
}

.sidebar-logo:hover {
    background-color: var(--box-bg);
}

.sidebar-item a {
    color: var(--grey-color)
}

.sidebar-logo img {
    width: 50px;
}

.content-wrapper {
    margin-top: 110px;
    margin-left: 170px;
}

.header-menu {
    display: flex;
    /*align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*justify-content: left;*/
    font-size: 18px;
}

.header-item ~ .header-item {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

li.active {
    border-bottom: 2.5px solid #E3AA1E;
}

li.active a {
    color: #E2E2E2;
}

.header-item a {
    color: #9f9f9f;
}

.content-wrapper li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.list-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.item:hover {
    background-color: var(--box-bg);
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-right: 10px solid gold;
    border-left: 10px solid gold;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.item a {
    color: unset;
}

.item img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
}

.movie-name {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 85%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.movie-time {
    margin-top: 3px;
    color: #9F9F9F;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.movie-description {
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    html {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .msg-login {
        width: 800px;
    }

    .main-login {
        width: 400px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    html {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .msg-login {
        width: 400px;
    }

    .main-login {
        width: 250px;
    }

    .box_input_auth {
        width: 150px;
    }

    .login_btn, .register_btn {
        width: 200px;
    }

    .option_help {
        margin-left: 50px;
        display: flex;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    html {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .info-login-msg {
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    
    .msg-login {
        width: 250px;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Freezy I hope this will help you.

Comment: Omg, is it working perfectly! Thank you sooo much!